# H2O parses files types differently

Tags: python, csv, parquet, h2o

I am seeing strange behaviour between file types when parsing the data. I am using a small dataset (200 rows, 34 columns) that is in both parquet and CSV format.

When I parse the CSV file I can see that boolean values are correctly identified as an enum see below (male/female):

```
print(h2o_frame_csv.types)

{'C1': 'int', 'userId': 'int', 'itemId': 'int', 'rating': 'int', 'timestamp': 'int', 'movieId': 'int', 'movieTitle': 'enum', 'releaseDate': 'time', 'videoReleaseDate': 'int', 'imdbUrl': 'enum', 'unknown': 'int', 'Action': 'int', 'Adventure': 'int', 'Animation': 'int', 'Childrens': 'int', 'Comedy': 'int', 'Crime': 'int', 'Documentary': 'int', 'Drama': 'int', 'Fantasy': 'int', 'FilmNoir': 'int', 'Horror': 'int', 'Musical': 'int', 'Mystery': 'int', 'Romance': 'int', 'SciFi': 'int', 'Thriller': 'int', 'War': 'int', 'Western': 'int', 'age': 'int', 'occupation': 'enum', 'zipCode': 'int', 'male': 'enum', 'female': 'enum'}
```

However, when I used the parquet version of the files I am seeing the same values being treated as int values

```
print(h2o_frame_parquet.types)

{'Unnamed: 0': 'int', 'userId': 'int', 'itemId': 'int', 'rating': 'int', 'timestamp': 'int', 'movieId': 'int', 'movieTitle': 'enum', 'releaseDate': 'time', 'videoReleaseDate': 'int', 'imdbUrl': 'enum', 'unknown': 'int', 'Action': 'int', 'Adventure': 'int', 'Animation': 'int', 'Childrens': 'int', 'Comedy': 'int', 'Crime': 'int', 'Documentary': 'int', 'Drama': 'int', 'Fantasy': 'int', 'FilmNoir': 'int', 'Horror': 'int', 'Musical': 'int', 'Mystery': 'int', 'Romance': 'int', 'SciFi': 'int', 'Thriller': 'int', 'War': 'int', 'Western': 'int', 'age': 'int', 'occupation': 'enum', 'zipCode': 'int', 'male': 'int', 'female': 'int', '__index_level_0__': 'int'}
```

This becomes an issue when trying to train a classifier model. Some metrics are not available as h2o deems this be regressor rather than binomial. See below

```
print(f"For {file_type} dataset the metric class is {type(xgb.model_performance(xval=True))}")

For csv dataset the metric class is <class 'h2o.model.metrics_base.H2OBinomialModelMetrics'>

For parquet dataset the metric class is <class 'h2o.model.metrics_base.H2ORegressionModelMetrics'>
```

What is the reason for treating boolean values as numeric (int) when parsing the parquet file? Are booleans not considered categorical enums like in the CSV file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Revised based on comments and software updates from @MichalKurka below.]

Parquet files include metadata about the column type.  H2O-3 honors the metadata.

In csv files, the column type is guessed.

In H2O-3 versions 3.28.0.1 and higher, columns in a parquet dataset with a boolean type are treated as an enum value (aka categorical).   Prior versions of H2O-3 treated a parquet boolean column as a numeric value.

Comment: Yes I understand that but the column type is boolean for the columns, and I believe this line here is causing it to be treated as a numerical value rather than categorical- https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/391d03b28f311678289c543b30364ef6612b484f/h2o-parsers/h2o-parquet-parser/src/main/java/water/parser/parquet/ParquetParser.java#L266, Is this correct?

Comment: @user12302914 Good find: I'd suggest posting that as a bug (https://0xdata.atlassian.net/projects/PUBDEV/summary), and perhaps as a self-answer. Looks like parquet files need to work the same way as csv files for int (i.e. decide if just a few categories or if they are real numbers) and always treat boolean as enum? (P.S. But do wait for Tom's reply, in case we've both misunderstood that code!)

Comment: @TomKraljevic any thoughts on the above?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  The engineering team is taking a look at that.  It does appear to be inconsistent to me, as well.

Comment: You are right, I think this really is a bug. We turn booleans into 0/1 numeric but we could turn it to True/False categorical instead.

I filed an issue for you https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-7093

Comment: The fixed was merged and will be available in the next major release.

Comment: Thank you @MichalKurka for the quick turn around, is it possible for you to add an answer so that I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: If @MichalKurka adds an answer then please do mark it as accepted.  I also upvoted the question for finding a bug and updated my answer above to communicate the change for posterity.